# ReactDom is not defined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

[image]I am trying to write a basic program in reactjs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello React!</title>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.2/react.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.2/react-dom.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-core@5.8.38/browser.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="example"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">
        ReactDOM.render(
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
        document.getElementById('example')
        );
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The above program works fine. But when I move the content inside my script file to a separate app.jsx file it shows error that reactDom is not defined.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello React!</title>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.2/react.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.2/react-dom.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-core@5.8.38/browser.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="example"></div>
    <script type="text/babel" src="app.jsx">

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and my app.jsx looks like:

```
ReactDom.render(
    <h1>Hello React!!!</h1>,
    document.getElementById('example')
)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The global is `ReactDOM` (note `DOM` is all uppercase).

Comment: After making these changes I got a different error Minified React error #37

Comment: Try using the non-minified JS bundles (remove `.min`) from the URLs. You'll get a more helpful message.

Comment: Yeah it worked after removing .min. So is there some kind of error in min file?

Comment: I don't know why that would make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Correct syntax is `ReactDOM.render`.

See example below:

```js
ReactDOM.render(
    <h1>Hello React!!!</h1>,
    document.getElementById('example')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>


<div id="example"></div>
```